# flutter audio_manager ios delay in player when playing next song

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, audio, avplayer

[screen capture of my ios device showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzOlU.jpg)

I'm using the following library  [audio_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_manager#-readme-tab-), as it is quite new, is working for ios and android and actually has notification handling. On android it uses android mediaplayer, on ios it uses AVplayer.

If you're adding the given example there and change the list of songs which contains 1 local and 1 network song with network songs only and test it on real ios device I have an issue which I actually can't fix.

First up, this is my list which I replaced in the demo project:

```
final list = [
    {
      "title": "Ambia",
      "desc": "Taeo Kol",
      "url": "https://www.basicmethods.org/mp3/BM_traxx_25.mp3",
      "coverUrl": "https://www.countrymusicnews.de/images/stories/cd/RodneyAtkins-CaughtUpInTheCountryLP.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Terror",
      "desc": "Taeo Kol",
      "url": "https://dreaddymck.com/Public/MUSIC/FEATURING/project%2081.mp3",
      "coverUrl": "https://images.rapgenius.com/ed068b8684cbf71e619ed940d37b0b80.900x892x1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Confusing",
      "desc": "Ministri",
      "url": "https://ia800305.us.archive.org/30/items/return_201605/return.mp3",
      "coverUrl": "https://static.vibe.com/uploads/2015/01/MCM9.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Dromeda",
      "desc": "Ministri",
      "url": "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/Creative_Commons/Dead_Combo/CC_Affiliates_Mixtape_1/Dead_Combo_-_01_-_Povo_Que_Cas_Descalo.mp3",
      "coverUrl": "https://static.vibe.com/uploads/2015/01/MCM7-600x600.jpg"
    }
  ];
```

and here is the example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:audio_manager/audio_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  bool isPlaying = false;
  Duration _duration;
  Duration _position;
  double _slider;
  double _sliderVolume;
  String _error;
  num curIndex = 0;
  PlayMode playMode = AudioManager.instance.playMode;

  final list = [
    {
      "title": "Assets",
      "desc": "local assets playback",
      "url": "assets/audio.mp3",
      "coverUrl": "assets/ic_launcher.png"
    },
    {
      "title": "network",
      "desc": "network resouce playback",
      "url": "https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.m4a",
      "coverUrl": "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
    }
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPlatformState();
    setupAudio();
    // loadFile();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // 释放所有资源
    AudioManager.instance.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setupAudio() {
    List<AudioInfo> _list = [];
    list.forEach((item) => _list.add(AudioInfo(item["url"],
        title: item["title"], desc: item["desc"], coverUrl: item["coverUrl"])));

    AudioManager.instance.audioList = _list;
    AudioManager.instance.intercepter = true;
    AudioManager.instance.play(auto: false);

    AudioManager.instance.onEvents((events, args) {
      print("$events, $args");
      switch (events) {
        case AudioManagerEvents.start:
          print("start load data callback");
          _position = AudioManager.instance.position;
          _duration = AudioManager.instance.duration;
          _slider = 0;
          setState(() {});
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.ready:
          print("ready to play");
          _error = null;
          _sliderVolume = AudioManager.instance.volume;
          _position = AudioManager.instance.position;
          _duration = AudioManager.instance.duration;
          setState(() {});
          AudioManager.instance.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 10));
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.seekComplete:
          _position = AudioManager.instance.position;
          _slider = _position.inMilliseconds / _duration.inMilliseconds;
          setState(() {});
          print("seek event is completed. position is [$args]/ms");
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.buffering:
          print("buffering $args");
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.playstatus:
          isPlaying = AudioManager.instance.isPlaying;
          setState(() {});
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.timeupdate:
          _position = AudioManager.instance.position;
          _slider = _position.inMilliseconds / _duration.inMilliseconds;
          setState(() {});
          AudioManager.instance.updateLrc(args["position"].toString());
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.error:
          _error = args;
          setState(() {});
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.ended:
          AudioManager.instance.next();
          break;
        case AudioManagerEvents.volumeChange:
          _sliderVolume = AudioManager.instance.volume;
          setState(() {});
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  void loadFile() async {
    final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // Please make sure the `test.mp3` exists in the document directory
    final file = File("${appDocDir.path}/test.mp3");
    AudioInfo info = AudioInfo("file://${file.path}",
        title: "file",
        desc: "local file",
        coverUrl: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png");

    list.add(info.toJson());
    AudioManager.instance.audioList.add(info);
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    try {
      platformVersion = await AudioManager.instance.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin audio player'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: volumeFrame(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(list[index]["title"],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        subtitle: Text(list[index]["desc"]),
                        onTap: () => AudioManager.instance.play(index: index),
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(),
                    itemCount: list.length),
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Text(_error != null
                      ? _error
                      : "${AudioManager.instance.info.title} lrc text: $_position")),
              bottomPanel()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomPanel() {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: songProgress(context),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: getPlayModeIcon(playMode),
                onPressed: () {
                  playMode = AudioManager.instance.nextMode();
                  setState(() {});
                }),
            IconButton(
                iconSize: 36,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.skip_previous,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () => AudioManager.instance.previous()),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                bool playing = await AudioManager.instance.playOrPause();
                print("await -- $playing");
              },
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              icon: Icon(
                isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                size: 48.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
                iconSize: 36,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.skip_next,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () => AudioManager.instance.next()),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("click menu");
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  Widget getPlayModeIcon(PlayMode playMode) {
    switch (playMode) {
      case PlayMode.sequence:
        return Icon(
          Icons.repeat,
          color: Colors.black,
        );
      case PlayMode.shuffle:
        return Icon(
          Icons.shuffle,
          color: Colors.black,
        );
      case PlayMode.single:
        return Icon(
          Icons.repeat_one,
          color: Colors.black,
        );
    }
    return Container();
  }

  Widget songProgress(BuildContext context) {
    var style = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          _formatDuration(_position),
          style: style,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
            child: SliderTheme(
                data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                  trackHeight: 2,
                  thumbColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  overlayColor: Colors.blue,
                  thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                    disabledThumbRadius: 5,
                    enabledThumbRadius: 5,
                  ),
                  overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                    overlayRadius: 10,
                  ),
                  activeTrackColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                child: Slider(
                  value: _slider ?? 0,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _slider = value;
                    });
                  },
                  onChangeEnd: (value) {
                    if (_duration != null) {
                      Duration msec = Duration(
                          milliseconds:
                              (_duration.inMilliseconds * value).round());
                      AudioManager.instance.seekTo(msec);
                    }
                  },
                )),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          _formatDuration(_duration),
          style: style,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration d) {
    if (d == null) return "--:--";
    int minute = d.inMinutes;
    int second = (d.inSeconds > 60) ? (d.inSeconds % 60) : d.inSeconds;
    String format = ((minute < 10) ? "0$minute" : "$minute") +
        ":" +
        ((second < 10) ? "0$second" : "$second");
    return format;
  }

  Widget volumeFrame() {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.audiotrack,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            AudioManager.instance.setVolume(0);
          }),
      Expanded(
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
              child: Slider(
                value: _sliderVolume ?? 0,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _sliderVolume = value;
                    AudioManager.instance.setVolume(value, showVolume: true);
                  });
                },
              )))
    ]);
  }
}
```

If you start playing a song and switch to the lockscreen where the media player is, everything just works fine, the only thing you may notice is, that it takes quite long time until the song starts playing. (The plugin buffers actually) If you toggle the next song icon on the mediaplayer, play icon stops for a millisecond, resumes, then the song is still playing like 3-5 seconds before finally playing the next song.

If you check the debugging console, song starts buffering later there, there is an error somewhere in the swift code I think, if you press next or previous on the mediaplayer, it should directly switch to the next song, which it is actually not working right now.

Hopefully someone can help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the newest update of Audio Manager, the problem has been fixed.

audio_manager: ^0.5.4

You can download it here: https://pub.dev/packages/audio_manager#-installing-tab-